# How can I query Firebase for an equalTo boolean parameter?

Tags: javascript, json, firebase

My database looks like

```
{
  "chats" : {
    "-K5hUtxNOPLWwRTb8fAj" : {
      "clientId" : 893,
      "messages" : {
        "-K5hUtyCwWuPeFT0cSXr" : {
          "chatKey" : "-K5hUtxNOPLWwRTb8fAj",
          "messageText" : "new message",
          "timestamp" : 1450314801055,
          "userId" : "19eaa3f0-4ab3-44b4-b418-03b64ca2313a"
        },
        "-K5hUvwKsAOvuvt-ymFG" : {
          "chatKey" : "-K5hUtxNOPLWwRTb8fAj",
          "messageText" : "did this work",
          "timestamp" : 1450314809127,
          "userId" : "48f7a208-5647-4d0e-921c-c49595de1db2"
        }
      },
      "newQuestion" : false,
      "startedByUserId" : "19eaa3f0-4ab3-44b4-b418-03b64ca2313a"
    },
    "-K5hVKjs4SkSHD7WTh1I" : {
      "clientId" : 518,
      "messages" : {
        "-K5hVNzPKNgxLCgkfInI" : {
          "chatKey" : "-K5hVKjs4SkSHD7WTh1I",
          "messageText" : "this is new",
          "timestamp" : 1450314928109,
          "userId" : "19eaa3f0-4ab3-44b4-b418-03b64ca2313a"
        }
      },
      "newQuestion" : true,
      "startedByUserId" : "19eaa3f0-4ab3-44b4-b418-03b64ca2313a"
    }
  }
}
```

How can I get all `chats` that have a `newQuestion` set to `true`? I've tried a few different queries, the latest is:

```
firebaseDb.child("chats/newQuestion").equalTo(true).once("value"...
```

But that complains about an order being needed for a boolean?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to specify an `orderBy` method first.

```
var query = firebaseDb.child("chats").orderByChild("newQuestion").equalTo(true);
```

[Here's the Firebase docs on querying.](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/retrieving-data.html#section-queries)

Comment: What if I want to order all chats by another field - like `clientId`? But only when `newQuestion` is `true`?

Comment: You would need to change your data structure to key off of clientId. So you could do `var query = firebaseDb.child("chats").child(clientId).orderByChild("newQuestion").equalTo(true);`

Comment: And how would I query for multiple conditions? `clientId` = 10 and `newQuestion` = true?

Comment: Firebase only supports one orderBy method. When the query gets more complex it's easier to sort on the client side. Especially if the record set is less than 1,000.